# How to allow Facebook logins from other people than myself?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a website on which people can login using facebook. This currently works all fine when I login with my facebook account. The weird thing is that when anybody else wants to login I get an error on facebook saying something like (translated from Dutch):

> App isn't configured: The developers of this app have this app not set
>   up correctly for Facebook login.

I don't understand why it works with my own account, but it doesn't with other people's accounts. Does anybody know what the source is of this evil, and how I can solve it? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your App public, just go to "Status & Review" and use the switch right next to the following text:

> Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?

Also make sure to add the platform "Website" in the "Settings" tab.

Comment: Ahaha... Synchron-posting

Comment: yeah. i was a tiny bit faster though, hehe

Comment: Thanks! Just a question: if it is set to public, is it also published somewhere on the web? Or can I continue to silently test it without attracting too much attention to it yet?

Comment: no, it´s not published somewhere, you can still just test it. it´s a switch that gets forgotton to turn on quite often :) - you can also just flip it right when you create the app in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Have you marked your app as publically available? Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and select your app, go to "Status & Review" and push the button to make it available.